# Symfony2 Add Commands to be Run for Dev Environment

Tags: php, symfony

How can I make Symfony2 run certain Commands every time the page loads when it is in the Dev environment?

We use TypeScript and I have build a command which will grab all of my TypeScript and compile it. The only problem is, I have to do this manually every time I upload some new code, which slows things down when debugging (I'm perfectly fine doing it this way for Production though).

I'd like it to call that Command every page load (if some of the files have changed since it last compiled... all logic I'll built out). I just need to know where I should hook in to.

Thanks.

Comment: The `kernel.request` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are set on using Symfony to compile your TypeScript I would try using an [event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html)

You could try something like this (untested):

Add a service to the `config_dev.yml` file so that the listener only runs in the dev environment

```
# app/config/config_dev.yml 
services:        
      compileTypeScript:
        class: myApp\TypescriptBundle\Controller\TypescriptComiler
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: 64 }
```

I'm not exactly sure how priority works, but 64 seemed to hit the sweet spot for me.

Create the class you referenced above and add in your code to compile the TypeScript.

```
//Class
class TypescriptCompiler extends controller
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {       
        // compile your TypeScript here
    }
}
```

Comment: That could work. Like I said, I'm not going to do it EVERY time, just whenever it has changed (so it's only a performance slowdown when there is a change, which is analogous to having to run the command myself. I use Symfony to compile because there is some bundle-centric logic related to what compiles where.

Comment: Cool, this method should work well for you then. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: So, I decided to not run it as a Command after reading the last paragraph of this: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/console/introduction.html. Instead I'll be refactoring to pull the logic out of the command and then run that logic directly in both the command and in my event listener. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use Symfony to compile every time (slow), you could setup a [grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com) [watch task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) to watch the file then compile every time there is a change. To do this you would have to be comfortable with setting up [node.js](http://nodejs.com) on your development system. All in all, I find it is kind of nice to completely decouple the client and the server.

Comment: I'd rather not do a grunt task, or any other sort of "watch" because we have 2-3 servers in actual (at least) and it makes systems more tricky to maintain.

Comment: no problem, just a suggestion. It is a little bit of extra work to set up, but it works well for me compiling coffee script.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a valid approach. Just doesn't work quite well for me. Also, like I mentioned elsewhere, there is some bundle-centric logic for how things get compiled.

Answer (score 0):

We are looking at triggering grunt when we do a prod deployment - to perform the optimisations.

Dev uses the raw files and client side implementations.